# window scroll only one fire

Tags: javascript, css

I have one problem, I have chart animation, everything looks ok but... I would like that this code will fire only one, but on every scroll down or up chart are start again. Look, percents description on every scroll are starting again. Is option to fire this code only first scroll? Thank you for help

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.holder').offset().top) {
        $('.bar').each(function(i) {
            var $bar = $(this);
            $(this).append('<span class="count"></span>')
            setTimeout(function() {
                $bar.css('width', $bar.attr('data-percent'));
            }, i * 100);
        });

        $('.count').each(function() {
            $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).parent('.bar').attr('data-percent')
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function(now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
                }
            });
        });
    }
})
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400, 400italic|Montserrat:400, 700);
 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
q, blockquote {
    quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    content:"";
    content: none;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    color: #333;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    padding: 2%;
}
.wrap {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: .5em 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul li {
    line-height: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-size: .85em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    clear: both;
}
ul li:before {
    content:"\2023";
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}
.bar {
    background: #e74c3c;
    width: 0;
    margin: .25em 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    transition: width 2s, background .2s;
    clear: both;
}
.bar:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background: #ed7669;
}
.bar .label {
    font-size: .75em;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    width: 8em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.bar .label.light {
    background: #575757;
}
.count {
    position: absolute;
    right: .25em;
    top: .75em;
    padding: .15em;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
     <h1>Animated Bar Graphs</h1>

    <div class="holder">
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="85%"><span class="label">Photoshop</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="75%"><span class="label light">Illustrator</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="65%"><span class="label">Indesign</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="90%"><span class="label light">HTML</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="90%"><span class="label">CSS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="80%"><span class="label light">jQuery</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="85%"><span class="label light">RWD</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="75%"><span class="label">PHP</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="80%"><span class="label light">WordPress</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="70%"><span class="label">SASS/SCSS</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script simply appends a `span` to `holder` div. so check if it has already a `span` with `count` class. if so, continue.

```js
 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.holder').offset().top) {
        $('.bar').each(function(i) {
            var $bar = $(this);
          if($(this).find('span.count').length !== 0) return;
  
            console.log("span is added");

            $(this).append('<span class="count"></span>')
            setTimeout(function() {
                $bar.css('width', $bar.attr('data-percent'));
            }, i * 100);
            $(window).off('scroll'); 
        });

        $('.count').each(function() {
            $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).parent('.bar').attr('data-percent')
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function(now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
                }
            });
        });
    }
})
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400, 400italic|Montserrat:400, 700);
 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
q, blockquote {
    quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    content:"";
    content: none;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    color: #333;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    padding: 2%;
}
.wrap {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: .5em 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul li {
    line-height: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-size: .85em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    clear: both;
}
ul li:before {
    content:"\2023";
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}
.bar {
    background: #e74c3c;
    width: 0;
    margin: .25em 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    transition: width 2s, background .2s;
    clear: both;
}
.bar:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background: #ed7669;
}
.bar .label {
    font-size: .75em;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    width: 8em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.bar .label.light {
    background: #575757;
}
.count {
    position: absolute;
    right: .25em;
    top: .75em;
    padding: .15em;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
     <h1>Animated Bar Graphs</h1>

    <div class="holder">
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="85%"><span class="label">Photoshop</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="75%"><span class="label light">Illustrator</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="65%"><span class="label">Indesign</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="90%"><span class="label light">HTML</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="90%"><span class="label">CSS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="80%"><span class="label light">jQuery</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="85%"><span class="label light">RWD</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="75%"><span class="label">PHP</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="80%"><span class="label light">WordPress</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="70%"><span class="label">SASS/SCSS</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is average solution because, span is still adding again and again. This is very slow application

Comment: And I would like that this scroll will only one fire

Comment: @V.R no, it is not adding again and again. put a console log before adding span and see how many times the line running. see my update

Comment: Yes I see, but I consider is an option to do this code only in first scroll, for next scrolling this code will no fire

Comment: like @hobo  said you can use `on` function and unlink after its executed. check my answer. but still, its checked if its run before in somewhere Jquery library. you can now compare runtime. let me know if there is any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `.on` and unlink the event inside:

```js
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.holder').offset().top) {
        $('.bar').each(function(i) {
            var $bar = $(this);
            $(this).append('<span class="count"></span>')
            setTimeout(function() {
                $bar.css('width', $bar.attr('data-percent'));
            }, i * 100);
        });
        $(window).off('scroll'); 
        $('.count').each(function() {
            $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).parent('.bar').attr('data-percent')
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                step: function(now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400, 400italic|Montserrat:400, 700);
 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
q, blockquote {
    quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    content:"";
    content: none;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    color: #333;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    padding: 2%;
}
.wrap {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: .5em 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul li {
    line-height: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-size: .85em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    clear: both;
}
ul li:before {
    content:"\2023";
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}
.bar {
    background: #e74c3c;
    width: 0;
    margin: .25em 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    transition: width 2s, background .2s;
    clear: both;
}
.bar:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background: #ed7669;
}
.bar .label {
    font-size: .75em;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    width: 8em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.bar .label.light {
    background: #575757;
}
.count {
    position: absolute;
    right: .25em;
    top: .75em;
    padding: .15em;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
     <h1>Animated Bar Graphs</h1>

    <div class="holder">
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="85%"><span class="label">Photoshop</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="75%"><span class="label light">Illustrator</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="65%"><span class="label">Indesign</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="90%"><span class="label light">HTML</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="90%"><span class="label">CSS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="80%"><span class="label light">jQuery</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="85%"><span class="label light">RWD</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="75%"><span class="label">PHP</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="80%"><span class="label light">WordPress</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="70%"><span class="label">SASS/SCSS</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```